# Consulta no Banco de dados com php e mysqli Não retorna dados como deveria

Tags: php, mysql

estou listando algumas informações do banco de dados mysql, algo bem simples a princípio mas estou com o seguinte problema:

Executo o código para pesquisar a partir de um form e listar os dados conforme a pesquisa. O problema é que, algumas termos que consta no Banco de dados o php não retorna como "nada encontrado", o que é estranho é que: Se eu fizer a mesma consulta direto no sql ele retorna todos os dados corretamente conforme estão no banco de dados.

RESUMÃO: FAÇO A PESQUISA COM PHP USANDO FORM, MAS RETORNA EM VÁRIOS CASOS COMO NÃO ENCONTRADO. MAS SE EXECUTO O MESMO CÓDIGO DIRETO DIRETO NO SQL, RETORNA OS DADOS CORRETAMENTE.

MEU CÓDIGO DE BUSCA:

```
SELECT * FROM `NOME DA TABELA` WHERE title LIKE '%$pesquisa%' OR code LIKE '%$pesquisa%'
```

Este processo é tão simples que to perdendo os cabelos por este erro. Alguém poderia dar uma ideia, fazendo um grande favor?

Comment: Provavelmente você está tendo erro com sql-injection, não está causando "invasão", mas esta causando erro de sintaxe na query e como você não trata os erros provavelmente você escreveu mal o PHP e por isso não sabe que houve um erro, só envia para a saida "nada encontrado", de qualquer forma ao invés de usar strings no PHP para consultar, prefira o `bind_param` https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php, que vai resolver o sql-injection e erros de sintaxe gerados pelas variaveis ou pode usar também o `mysqli_real_escape_string` nas variaveis.

Comment: Votei pra fechar pq sua pergunta não é clara, e como as informações passadas são poucas só pra pra presumir que o erro é com erro de sintaxe devido a variavel `$pesquisa` não ter sido tratada, logo as perguntas que linkei acima devem lhe ensinar como usar bind_param ou mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Foi muito boa sua resposta, agradeço muito. Agora estou refazendo o código e vou tratar os erros, também vou usar as orientações. Tão logo darei o feedback.

Comment: Problema resolvido seguindo a orientação acima do @GuilhermeNascimento
Refiz o código usando PDO, executei a consulta com prepare e bindValue.

a query ficou: "SELECT * FROM 'nome da tabela' WHERE title LIKE ?"
bindeValue(1, $pesquisa);

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Não precisava fazer em PDO, por falar nisso em questões como mysqlnd (native driver) o mysqli tem suporte o PDO não, o que é uma grande vantagem, pq o nativedriver ajuda a obter uma performance significativamente melhor, no link que postei acima do rray tem exemplo com mysqli: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3869/3635 ... mas que bom que você entendeu bem os binds ;)